# Entity framework: is it ok to map only a set of columns?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4

Let's say I have a table that consists of 100 columns, but I'm interested of making use (for reading, updating) of only two of these columns.

Is it OK if I create an entity that consist only of two properties? Or should I create an entity with 100 properties and map all the 100 columns and later read only two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never done that with code first but using the edmx - database first style entity framework I have and it worked fine.  You'll get much better performance and have a lot less noise in your code base.  In a code first environment you might have to do a

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
```

and be very careful with your migrations, but it sounds like you're working with an existing database and probably won't be doing any migrations anyway.